# Dynamically adding columns to query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic

I am trying to create a dynamic query that selects a specific column based on an error code.

For Example I have an error table (ErrorTable) that contains multiple columns:

```
Transaction Number 
Transaction Amount
Transaction Date
Error Code
Error Description
+100 other columns
```

Errors Table

```
Error Code
Error Description
Error Column
```

I am trying to get a query that would get the following:

```
ErrorCode
ErrorDescription
ErrorColumn (Column Based On Error Code)
```

I tried using dynamic SQL like the following and still got just the name of the column returned, maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
DECLARE @SQL VarChar(1000)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT et.ErrorCode, et.ErrorDescription, e.ErrorColumn 
               FROM ErrorTable et
                   INNER JOIN Errors e ON e.ErrorCodeID = et.ErrorCode'
Exec ( @SQL)
```

If I use @ErrorColumn = 'TransactionDate' instead of e.ErrorColumn in the dynamic query I get results, but with the query above I don't. Any ideas?

**Update 2**

I get the following results with the above query:

```
ErrorCode    ErrorDesc              TransactionDate    TransactionAmount
1            Invalid Trans Date     TransactionDate    TransactionAmount
2            Invalid Trans Amount   TransactionDate    TransactionAmount
```

I want the following:

```
ErrorCode    ErrorDesc              TransactionDate    TransactionAmount
1            Invalid Trans Date     May 1st            
2            Invalid Trans Amount                      65 Cats
```

Comment: Your example select statement is invalid.  You select ErrorCode without an aliased table prefix.  Which table is that coming from?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you have the name of the column stored in Errors.ErrorColumn and you want the error type to determine which column is selected. If the number of error types is not large, consider writing a CASE statement. Otherwise, you'll have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: what errors does it give you?

Comment: As written/edited it looks like it should work.

Comment: I'm with jonnyGold it looks like your query should be returning what you want. The join is correct and you are selecting the right columns. What aren't you able to get to work about it?

Comment: @jonnyGold Correct, it does work. However I can't get the dynamic query to return actual table values. It just returns 'TransactionDate' instead of May 1st.

Comment: @buzzzzjay I don't think you've shown the code that causes that result. All you've said is "If I use `@ErrorColumn`..." but you haven't actually included any code that mentions `@ErrorColumn` at all.

Comment: Also why does one column have `ErrorCodeID` which matches to `ErrorCode` in another table? I'd expect the former to be an integer (surrogate key of some kind, probably `IDENTITY`), and the latter to be something more human readable. If they're both `ErrorCodeID`s, why not call them the same thing in both tables?

Comment: So, you want to generate a query based on the output of the first, right?

Comment: Now you're pulling both TransactionDate and TransactionAmount for both rows. Suddenly it seems that the ErrorColumn value in ErrorTable is no longer relevant?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The main reason is I don't want to include the other 100+ fields in the table they are correct. I only would want to show values that are incorrect. So in the example above only the 2 columns were invalid.

Comment: But wasn't "TransactionDate" only invalid on the first row, and "TransactionAmount" only invalid on the second row?

Comment: Also are you really letting people store dates in whatever format they want? Is `06/07/2012` July 6th or June 7th? Who can determine what a user meant? And transaction amount can really be measured in cats? I think there are some serious data type issues here.

Comment: I am not letting people store data in what ever format they want. That is why these values are in the error table because they didn't meet the set specifications.

Comment: So you still need to explain (or help us understand) why you return 12.58 when the ErrorColumn is TransactionDate. What value does the TransactionAmount have when the problem wasn't in that column? Why not just return all the columns that could have been the problem?

Comment: You are correct, I will update that. That value shouldn't have been returned. Your original answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you meaning to do this:

```
DECLARE @ErrorColumn SYSNAME = N'TransactionDate';
-- presumably the above is a parameter to the procedure

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT et.ErrorCode, et.ErrorDescription, et.' 
  + QUOTENAME(@ErrorColumn)
  + ' FROM dbo.ErrorTable AS et
      INNER JOIN dbo.Errors AS e
      ON e.ErrorCodeID = et.ErrorCode;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Based on further information, perhaps what you want is this:

```
SELECT et.ErrorCode, et.ErrorDescription, 
  TransactionDate   = CASE et.ErrorColumn WHEN N'TransactionDate' 
    THEN e.TransactionDate   ELSE NULL END,
  TransactionAmount = CASE et.ErrorColumn WHEN N'TransactionAmount' 
    THEN e.TransactionAmount ELSE NULL END
FROM dbo.ErrorTable AS et 
INNER JOIN dbo.Errors AS e
ON et.ErrorCode = e.ErrorCodeID;
```

Or this:

```
SELECT et.ErrorCode, et.ErrorDescription, 
  TransactionDate   = CASE et.ErrorColumn WHEN N'TransactionDate' 
    THEN e.TransactionDate   ELSE '' END,
  TransactionAmount = CASE et.ErrorColumn WHEN N'TransactionAmount' 
    THEN e.TransactionAmount ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.ErrorTable AS et 
INNER JOIN dbo.Errors AS e
ON et.ErrorCode = e.ErrorCodeID;
```

If you need to only return the columns that actually exist in the data set, it is slightly more convoluted. You basically have to build dynamic SQL to include only the columns you have to reference in the eventual query.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
  + et.ErrorColumn + ' = CASE et.ErrorColumn WHEN N''' 
  + et.ErrorColumn + ''' THEN e.' + et.ErrorColumn + ' ELSE NULL END'
FROM dbo.ErrorTable AS et INNER JOIN dbo.Errors AS e
ON et.ErrorCode = e.ErrorCodeID
GROUP BY et.ErrorColumn;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT et.ErrorCode, et.ErrorDescription' 
  + @sql + '
  FROM dbo.ErrorTable AS et 
INNER JOIN dbo.Errors AS e
ON et.ErrorCode = e.ErrorCodeID;';

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This works correctly as expected, but I wasn't wanting to pass in a parameter. Is there a way to do this without passing in a parameter and just using the value in the Errors table? This is what I meant that I got it to to work @ErrorColumn, I was meaning that if you pass in a parameter it works as expected (ie. returning table values). Thanks!

Comment: Okay, please show some sample data and desired results - we would have never guessed this based on what you have in the question now. Do you want this result for a specific row, or for all rows? E.g. if one error says TransactionDate and another says TransactionNumber, you want the same column to show May 1 for one row and 12345 for the other row?

Comment: Updated OP with details. Sorry for not wording my question clearly. The more I think about it, it might be better to use a parameter and run each error code separately. Thanks.